# Check field value in Dispform Sharepoint 2007

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've this code into Content editor Web part in Display Form of Sharepoint 2007:

```
<p>
    <script src="/GCAP/JQuery/jquery-1.5.js">
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
var sField1 = $('h3:contains("sino")').closest('td').next('td').text();
    alert("sField1:"+ sField1);
    if (sField1 == "No"){
       alert("prove");
    } 

});
    </script>

</p>
```

The variable sField1 is equal to "No", but when check it i don't show alert("prove").

Why, even if the value is the same, it doesn't go in "then" clause?

Thank for your help.

Regards,
Francesco

Comment: Try `if($.trim(sField1) == "No") { alert('prove') }` ; There might be spaces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.trim( str )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

> Description: Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```
if($.trim(sField1) == "No") { alert('prove') } ;
```